# Ubuntu 18.04.1 playing MP4 doesn't work

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

Installed on three (one dell latitude laptop, one dell all-in-one and one ASUS desktop) systems Ubuntu 18.0.1.
After install cannot play, with standard installed Totem player, on any of the systems movies in MP4 format. MKV works without issues.

Installed, following web instructions, ubuntu-restricted-axtras and other stuff. Also installed VLC, Smplayer and mpv players but still MP4 format doesn't want to play on any of the players on any of the three machines.

Started a player from the command line and examined a log file created by SMplayer and found identical error reported back:

```
[ffmpeg/demuxer] mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2: error reading header.
```

I can play the same MP4 files with players installed on Ubuntu 16.04.

Has somebody out there an idea what's wrong?

Comment: After installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras` I can play my mp4 files in 18.04.1 LTS. But the `mp4` container can contain music and videos encoded with various codecs, so in order to help us help you, please link to an `mp4` file, that you cannot play.

Comment: Show the complete output of `ffmpeg -i input.mp4`.